# How to import related tasks in TFS

Tags: tfs, alm

We have a set of dependent tasks in our legacy task tracking system that we want to import in TFS.
These tasks have predecessor - successor links and I can't seem to find a way to import them with these kind of relationships.
The only kind of relationships that I found were importable were parent - child. Here's the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286627.aspx).

Comment: No, that't not easy using Excel, but relatively simple using the Client Object Model (optionally from Powershell).

Comment: Is it at all possible by using Excel?